# How can EOSIO know the block number?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio-code

I have made my EOS world. If you follow the Nodeos biosboot manual (https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence), you would know eosio is to be BP. BP have to make a lot of blocks.
But when you start software by begin, the folder saved by blocks were empty. To my knowledge, Blockchain have to connect previous block.

So how can the software make the block when genesis starting?

if you know the source code, plz answer the code link